# Am I legally allowed to travel to France without a COVID vaccine, through a green-listed country, if my origin is amber-listed?

Tags: france

Travel from an amber-list country to France without the COVID vaccine is prohibited. Does this mean travel from an amber-list country, to a green-list country, and then onward to France is also prohibited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "legal" you mean, "will I be allowed to do this". Enforcement is (theoretically) at the point of boarding. So let's say you go from US to Norway (green zone), then Norway to France. As long as you meet the laxer green-zone requirements, you can travel from Norway to France. The regulations don't say anything about citizenship or "having been in an amber-zone country within X days". Whether or not you can get into Norway is another matter – most countries on the green list mandate a quarantine period for those who are not vaccinated.